# SharePoint Foundation 2010 development machine installation problems

Tags: installation, development

I'm having problems installing development machine for SharePoint (Foundation) 2010. This is what I did so far on the same machine:

1. Installed a clean Windows 7 x64 with 4GB of RAM without being part of any domain. Just a simple standalone machine.
2. Enabled IIS related features as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx) except IIS6 related ones (two of them)
3. Installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Development Edition (DB Engine and Writer being enabled but not SQL Agent)
4. Installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium
5. Started installing SharePoint Foundation 2010 with first extracting files, changing config to enable Windows 7 installation and then installed it as Server Farm (then Complete) to avoid installing SQL Express.
6. Created a separate SPF_CONFIG local user with `Logon as a service` right.
7. Opened SPF Management Shell and run `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` so I am able to use a non-domain username (SPF_CONFIG that I created in the previous step)

But all I get is this:
[image: Unknown error]

The outcome after this error is:

- Database `Sharepoint2010Config` is created
- User SPF_CONFIG is added to SQL Server and attached to this newly created database as `dbowner` (check below image)

[image]

- On SQL server level SPF_CONFIG user has following rights:

  - `dbcreator`
  - `securityadmin`
  - `public`

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with deploying to Windows 7, but you don't mention running the SharePoint prerequisites installer. (By the way, great question with lots of detail!)

Comment: @Alex Angas: Which prerequisites are you talking about? Because I've only found FilterPack in SPF2010 installation and I've installed it all right.

Comment: @Alex Angas: BTW thanks for the upvote (if it was you). I'm used to sometimes provide detailed questions and answers from www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Consider it resolved

I've followed two guides:

- [this blog post](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/installing-sharepoint-2010-privilege-service-accounts/)
- and [this MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx)

Step by step instructions I followed (may be helpful to someone else as well):

1. Then I've uninstalled SPF2010
2. Setup all accounts as described in the first document
3. Reinstalled all prerequisites and KBs described in MSDN resource.
4. Cancelled configuration wizard and ran Sharpoint PowerShell
5. Executed `New-SPConfigurationDatabase -AdministrationContentDatabaseName "SomeDBName"`
6. Command than asked me about all other missing info
7. Waited for the command to finish (few minutes)
8. And it succeeded
9. FINALLY!
10. Rerun `psconfigui` and finished configuration
11. Successfully launched SPF Admin Web.

*clap clap clap*

Answer (score 0):

What level of access does the user account have on the db server?  Is it just dbcreator or is it dbowner?  After the objects are created additional scripts are run.  I successfully used this process many times building (and rebuilding) an early demo setup I used.

Comment: On the database level it's defined as dbowner (as can bee seen on the above image I attached), but on the SQL Server level it's defined as described above (dbcreator, securityadmin and and public) and seen in the image

Comment: @Mike Oryszak: Did it work for you? Was your configuration like: Windows 7 x64, not connected to a domain, SQL Server 2008 R2 on the same machine, SPF 2010 Server Farm install (as complete) and then you ran powershell? Did ot actually work?